# How to handle empty array return in API response in retrofit 2 android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

The response of My API is as below.

```
{
"status": true,
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "property_data": [
      {
        "iPropertyID": "179",
        "sImage": "http://192.168.1.100:8080/protechdna/img/property/180219045755Etim%25web.jpg",
        "isImageUploaded": true,
        "sTypeOfPropertyMarked": "Sound System",
        "sModel": "201",
        "sMake": "sony",
        "sSerialNumber": "12456789",
        "sApproxValue": "149",
        "sDescriptionOfProperty": "Description Of Property Description Of Property",
        "sUniqueidentifyingFeatures": "Unique identifying features Unique identifying features Unique identifying features",
        "room_detail": {
          "iRoomID": "242",
          "sRoomName": "romania"
        },
        "pin_detail": {
          "iPinID": "788",
          "sPin": "12345",
          "kit_detail": {
            "iKitID": "6",
            "sTypeOfKit": "DNA Spray"
          }
        },
        "owner_detail": {
          "iUserID": "702",
          "sEmailID": "priyank.nyusoft@gmail.com",
          "full_name": "priyank Patel",
          "address_line": "Main street",
          "sPhone": "(999) 999-9999",
          "state_detail": {
            "iStateID": "41",
            "sStateName": "Ohio"
          },
          "county_detail": {
            "iCountyID": "2117",
            "sCountyName": "Portage"
          },
          "city_detail": {
            "iCityID": "20241",
            "sCityName": "Newton Falls"
          },
          "zipcode_detail": {
            "iZipCodeID": "18762",
            "sZipcode": "44444"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "bicycle_data": [
      {
        "iBicycleID": "357",
        "sImage": "http://192.168.1.100:8080/protechdna/img/property/220419021553101018213027hi%20res%20bike.jpg",
        "isImageUploaded": true,
        "sBicycleName": "catrike",
        "sModel": "fgfdg",
        "sMake": "dfgfg",
        "sSerialNumber": "gfhfghtgf",
        "sApproxValue": "456",
        "sBicycleColor": "gff",
        "sUniqueidentifyingFeatures": "fghfh",
        "bicycletype_detail": {
          "iBicycleTypeID": "3",
          "sTypeName": "Touring Bikes"
        },
        "pin_detail": {
          "iPinID": "788",
          "sPin": "12345",
          "kit_detail": {
            "iKitID": "6",
            "sTypeOfKit": "DNA Spray"
          }
        },
        "owner_detail": {
          "sEmailID": "bharat.nyusoft@gmail.com",
          "full_name": "golden bicycle New",
          "address_line": "t",
          "iUserID": "",
          "sPhone": "",
          "state_detail": {
            "iStateID": "12",
            "sStateName": "Florida"
          },
          "county_detail": {
            "iCountyID": "357",
            "sCountyName": "Leon"
          },
          "city_detail": {
            "iCityID": "3900",
            "sCityName": "Tallahassee"
          },
          "zipcode_detail": {
            "iZipCodeID": "13609",
            "sZipcode": "32312"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "iBicycleID": "356",
        "sImage": "http://192.168.1.100:8080/protechdna/img/property/020419084735041018112608hi%20res%20bike.jpg",
        "isImageUploaded": true,
        "sBicycleName": "catrike",
        "sModel": "erer 123",
        "sMake": "df",
        "sSerialNumber": "12456789012",
        "sApproxValue": "10",
        "sBicycleColor": "erer",
        "sUniqueidentifyingFeatures": "erer",
        "bicycletype_detail": {
          "iBicycleTypeID": "2",
          "sTypeName": "Cyclocross Bikes"
        },
        "pin_detail": {
          "iPinID": "788",
          "sPin": "12345",
          "kit_detail": {
            "iKitID": "6",
            "sTypeOfKit": "DNA Spray"
          }
        },
        "owner_detail": {
          "iUserID": "600",
          "sEmailID": "das@gmail.com",
          "full_name": "Das Patel",
          "address_line": "",
          "sPhone": "(123) 777-7007",
          "state_detail": null,
          "county_detail": null,
          "city_detail": null,
          "zipcode_detail": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "vehicle_data": [

    ],
    "accessory_data": [

    ]
  }
}
```

In last array you can see there is no data and showing brackets in vehicle_data and accessory_data
When API returns this kind of response the retrofit response is going in onfailure in place of onResponse.
can anyone help me in this ?
This is a 3rd party API which I am not able to modify response from server side.

Comment: There must be some issue with in the pojo itself. Can you add your pojo/model classes here ?

Comment: below is the model/pojo class link..

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GOGMsy09-Sdf6tKOpAJbGs7B_auBmFck

Comment: @Napolean Thanks for you support when I checked the things with results having data and having blank array found that when I was getting data they were sending JSON object and when there is no data they were sending JSON Array that's why the Model class was not parsing that and the result was going in failure in place of on success.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you are returning a list with no attributes type/data types,Let me clear If you had attributes/items on it you may make a pojo class to catch the response,so how do you think catch a response what has no model/pojo type class,so this is a exception causeing OnFailour method.
If you want to use this List put some attributes there and set them null,like what you did with your other lists

in other way you can be sure after you get a successful response if it is eampty or not,put this condition in your `OnResponse` method

```
if(response.body().toString().length()==0)
  {
    //array is empty
  }
```

Comment: That is a 3rd Party API that returns the value so I am not able to modify the response of the API.

Comment: I edited my answer and add some extra info check it,let me know if you achive it or not